# components inside components in react with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

By the will of fate I have to work with react.js using only ES3 standrad. So, jsx, class and other things.
Using React.createClass and React.createElement I managed to crate a interactive input component that reflects input text to the label above input field.
[image]

 The code for this is following:

```
requirejs.config({
    // module name mapped to CDN url
    paths: {
        // Require.js appends `.js` extension for you
        'react': 'https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react',
        'react-dom': 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom'
    }
});

requirejs(['react', 'react-dom'], function(React, ReactDOM) {
      'use strict';
      var Input;
      var cr, root;
      cr = React.createElement;

      Input = React.createClass({
        displayName: 'Input',

        getInitialState: function getInitialState() {return {typed: ''};},

        onChange: function onChange(event) {
          this.setState({typed: event.target.value});
        },

        render: function render() {
          return cr('div', null,
            cr('div', null, '=>' + this.state.typed),
            cr('input', { type: 'text', onChange: this.onChange.bind(this)})
            );
          }
        });

        root = Input;
        var app = document.getElementById('app');
        ReactDOM.render(cr(root, null), app);
});
```

but now I'm trying to create a new component with two Input components inside:

```
    InputBlock = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'InputBlock',
    render: function render() {
      return cr('div', null, 
        cr('Input', null), 
        cr('Input', null)
        );
      }
    });
```

And I expected to see two element with dynamic behavior, but get only two simple input fields:
[image]

I understand that I miss something obvious, but I'm very new to react.js and can't see the whole picture yet.
Please, help.

Full implementation of final code

```
requirejs.config({
    // module name mapped to CDN url
    paths: {
        // Require.js appends `.js` extension for you
        'react': 'https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react',
        'react-dom': 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom'
    }
});

requirejs(['react', 'react-dom'], function(React, ReactDOM) {
      'use strict';
      var Input, InputBlock;
      var cr, root;
      cr = React.createElement;

      Input = React.createClass({
        displayName: 'Input',

        getInitialState: function getInitialState() {return {typed: ''};},

        onChange: function onChange(event) {
          this.setState({typed: event.target.value});
        },

        render: function render() {
          return cr('div', null,
            cr('div', null, '=>' + this.state.typed),
            cr('input', { type: 'text', onChange: this.onChange.bind(this)})
            );
          }
        });

        InputBlock = React.createClass({
        displayName: 'InputBlock',
        render: function render() {
          return cr('div', null, 
            cr('Input', null), 
            cr('Input', null)
            );
          }
        });

        root = InputBlock;
        var app = document.getElementById('app');
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(root, null), app);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to have quotes around Input. As a string, it's using the built-in input, whereas you want the custom component. This code should work for InputBlock:

```
InputBlock = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'InputBlock',
  render: function render() {
    return cr('div', null, 
      cr(Input, null), 
      cr(Input, null)
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Great! That hepls me a lot! Buy the way do you have any idea why I received a lot of warnings on this code with the same text: Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See Input

Comment: Yep, it's this line `cr('input', { type: 'text', onChange: this.onChange.bind(this)})`. You should be able to just pass `{ type: 'text', onChange: this.onChange}`. As the warning message says, React.createClass auto-binds methods. If you were using ES6 class components, you would have to bind manually.